# Smart Tv app (css and Javascript) - How to cyclically display a video stream and cyclicaly login

Tags: javascript, css, samsung-smart-tv

I'm currently making a CCTV app wich uses a given link of the cameras stream and displays it.

the **CSS** code i'm using to display is:

```
#cam_int_1
{
    position: absolute;
    top : 169px;
    left : 721px;
    background: url('http://admin:4321@10.0.0.62/cgi-bin/video.cgi?msubmenu=mjpg');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: -1;
    height : 169px;
    width : 239px;   
}
```

now, I can get and display the stream!

The problem is that the cctv camera logs out and I lose the stream.

In the URL I give:

background: url('http:/**/admin:4321@10.0.0.62**/cgi-bin/video.cgi?msubmenu=mjpg');

The bold part Is where I make the login the first time..

Is there a way to cyclically update this URL with the same exact link so I can never loose the login connection to the cctv cam?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set the background URL via Javascript and use a Time Interval to cyclically update it.